# Macro works on one computer but not the other

Tags: vba, outlook

Fair warning - the code is not my own, so any ideas will be welcomed on how to change it.

```
Public Sub ChangeMeeting()

Dim oRequest As MeetingItem
Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem

Set oRequest = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
If oRequest.MessageClass = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request" Then
Set oAppt = oRequest.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)

' use this to autoaccept
Dim oResponse
Set oResponse = oAppt.Respond(olMeetingAccepted, True)

oResponse.Send

' set fields on the appt.
With oAppt
' .Categories = "Slipstick"
.BusyStatus = olFree
.Save ' use .Display if you want to see the appt. and set the reminder yourself
End With

End If

'delete the request from the inbox
oRequest.Delete

End Sub
```

This one's interesting. On my computer, it works just fine. However, on the other one it can be clicked on and clicked on, and nothing will happen. No errors, no popups, no nothing. So, I know that the code works, but is there any reason (rights?) that the exact same code would work on one and not the other?

Comment: both outlook the same version? 2010? or

Comment: iirc, Outlook VBA is usually disabled by default, try going into Macro settings and checking the security options.

Comment: Sometimes if you copied the **VbaProject.OTM** file to other computer, that computer needs to open VBE, expand the modules then exit, restart Outlook brings macro to work. you may want to add `Debug.Print` lines to help you see if there is nothing performed. Did you sign the macro?

Comment: Macro is unsigned, outlook is the same throughout the office, and I'll have a look at the security options. Edit: This is designed to have someone accept an appointment as free.

Comment: Most likely the if condition is not met. Can you visualize or msgbox `oRequest.MessageClass` ? or step through the code?

Comment: Not sure how to visualize/msgbox that - only just realized that after checking the security settings that it would run, but stop to a type mismatch, 13. I will have to further look into it to see if I can fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that VBA macros are allowed to run. Is the VBA macro run in Outlook at all? Did you try to debug it?

Do you get any errors in the code on another machines?

I'd suggest starting from breaking the chain of property and method calls and declaring them on separate lines of code. Thus, you will be able to find what property or method fails.

The code is based on the selected item in the Explorer:

```
Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
```

Is the selection not empty all the time?

```
 If oRequest.MessageClass = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request"
```

Does the selection contains the first item with the specified message class?

In general, VBA macros are not designed for distributing on multiple PCs. If you need to get a solution working on multiple machines you need to develop an add-in instead. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx) .

Finally, you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.

Comment: So - (sorry for getting back to you so late), I've recreated it on my own work laptop (other one is a co-worker's laptop) and it works fine on my own. Ran a few test meetings through it and it did what it was supposed to. Still at a loss as to why it works on one and not the other. 

Did try to debug it to no avail because not one message popped up. Like I said, no errors on my own machine. However, I am an IT admin in my workplace and probably have more rights than she does. Yet the macro worked at one point and does not work now. No clue why.